# Python: reconstruct image from difference

Tags: python, opencv, difference, scikit-image

Using the following code I calculated the difference matrix between two images:

```
import time
import cv2
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

cap = VideoStream(src=0, framerate=30).start()
cap.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

time.sleep(2)

image1 = cap.read()
time.sleep(0.1)
image2 = cap.read()

image1_gray = rgb2gray(image1)
image2_gray = rgb2gray(image2)

score, difference = structural_similarity(image1_gray, image2_gray, full=True)
```

Now I need to apply this difference to the second image in order to extract a (480,640,3) RGB image, where the only colored pixels are the different ones extracted, and the others are "empty" (black or transparent maybe?).

Is there any way to do this since the difference calculated is a 1 channel image (480,640)?
I should also replace those pixels to the first image, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I also tryed this approach:

```
encode_params = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 80,
                 int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_PROGRESSIVE), 1]

# to calculate diff:
diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
_, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', diff, encode_params)

# to recontruct the image
diff = cv2.imdecode(buffer, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
prev_frame[diff != 0] = diff[diff != 0]
```

but the result is not as expected

Comment: that is `scikit-image`, not `opencv` -- [mre] please

Comment: that scikit method is only an option among those I've tryied, but I''m not tied to that, probably opencv has something better?

Comment: Maybe you could share images of what you have, what you got and what you want? Note that OpenCV buffers images so your two images may not be 100ms apart.

Comment: I'm currently reading frames from my usb camera using cv2.VideoCapture(0). First image is the first capture and the second one is the second capture. What I get is a white image more or less. More than a working example, it would be very appreciated if someone has any idea on how to deal with this king of problems.